# TYPO3 Inline element sorting does not work correctly

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.7.x, typo3-tca

After this post [TYPO3 Inline element appearance configuration partially does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51374987/typo3-inline-element-appearance-configuration-partially-does-not-work) i was able to achive what i wanted. The problem now, is that when i drag a child up or down, the sorting thing won't work.

The image:

[image]

Now when i move the children in a different position (either with the arrows or the burger menu sign), the new order will be saved in backend, but in frontend the order won't change. I assume it has something to do with the database, but at this point i have no idea what to do.

**EDIT:**
On my database i have the column sorting, and for every item is different. How can i use this column to order the elements?

**Code Example:**

```
<f:for each="{myContent}" as="content">
      <f:format.html>{content.data.content_text}</f:format.html>
</f:for>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem. Since i do not have a domain model, i used dataProccessing in order to get my objects. So, all i had to do is to add a line which was `orderBy = sorting`. So the code looks like this:

```
myElement < lib.contentElement
myElement {
    templateRootPaths.10 = {$Private}Templates/ContentElements/
    partialRootPaths.10 = {$Private}Partials/ContentElements/
    templateName = myElement.html
    dataProcessing {
        330 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
        330 {
            table = myElement_table
            pidInList = this
            where.field = uid 
            where.dataWrap = tt_content = |
            orderBy = sorting
            as = myElement
            dataProcessing {
                370 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
                370 {
                    references.fieldName = image
                    as = images
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Problem solved.

A big thank you to @Bernd Wilke πφ for trying to help me with literally all my TYPO3 questions.

Answer (score 1):

when you fetch the the inline elements you need to take the sorting column into account. that would happen primarily in the DB request which probably is done in your domain controller. maybe you need to redefine some methods.

If you use the build-in functions of TYPO3 you need to configure your relation accordingly.
Looking into the [manual](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/7.6/Reference/Columns/Inline/Index.html?highlight=foreign_sortbi#foreign-sortby) I find the value `foreign_sortby` where you declare the sorting field. maybe you just use the default field `sorting`.

Comment: I dont have a domain controller. I just have a sorting column on my database and defined on the tca

Comment: answer enhanced.

Comment: that means that i will have to add a columns with the name foreign_sortby so the new sorting values can be saved, right?

Comment: no. you need to declare an option `foreign_sortby` in your TCA (I assume it's from the referenced SO question) with the value `sorting` (which is the default column name for sorting in TYPO3) and o course you need that column in the referenced table. Have a look into the linked manual.